# Using the output of previous iteration as the input of the current iteration using mapply in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mapply

I have a long line of optimizations to use in mapply and each iteration is similar to next. I would like to use the output of the previous iterations optimized values as a starting point of the current iteration. Is it possible somehow? Or can I do it without much sweat using another package in R?

To clarify, let's say I have a vector of 100 values. In each iteration I take 50 of them starting from 1:50, 2:51 etc. to fit a model with 3 parameters. The output is a data set of 3 columns and 51 rows. I want to speed up the process since the subsequent iterations have almost the same data.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to do and how you expect to speed up the process. After you fit a model using some parameters indexed 1:50, you expect fitting a model to parameters indexed 2:51 to be fast, using the previous iteration? That sounds like it depends on the model. (If you want to do what you said in your title, i.e. use the output of an iteration as input to the next, this is done using `Reduce()`.)

Comment: Well think of Model1 for data 1:50 and Model2 for data 2:51 and parameters Par1_1, Par1_2, Par1_3 and same for model 2. Since the data is similar I expect having optimized parameters from Model1 as  starting values of Model2 will have an effect on the performance and speed. I am not totally sure but it seems like a good bet.

Comment: OK, I see. So let's say that you want to fit N models. You need a function `f(init, data)` that takes in the data (e.g. 1:50) and initial parameters for *one* iteration and outputs the initial parameters for the *next* iteration. Then if datalist is a list of length N whose ith component is the data for the ith iteration, you need `Reduce(f, datalist, init0)`, where init0 is the initialisation of the first iteration. I guess somewhere inside `f` you must also save the output of fitting each model. Does this make sense?

Comment: You sure this is the best approach?  What are you going to do with your 50 output sets of optimized parameters?  If it's all from the same population, what are you trying to learn?

Comment: The real application is the daily inference of GHYP parameters from log-returns data of SPX of 20 years with 1-2-3-5 and 10 years lookback period. Unfortunately it takes huge amount of time and I encountered difficulties in terms of optimization stability. I thought perhaps it would help.